# On the definition of vector measures

Tags: measure-theory

I'm working through a model of transportation taking place in a good domain $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$, you can assume that it's open, connected, bounded and with as-smooth-as-you-wish boundary. At some point, a vector meausure $\boldsymbol{\operatorname{y}}$ in $\Omega$ (I assume that it's on the Borel sigma algebra of $\Omega$ with the topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^d$) is defined by means of an operator $$ \langle\, \boldsymbol{\operatorname{y}} , \cdot \; \rangle : C(\overline{\Omega},\mathbb{R}^d)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\;.$$ I don't know if this is a standard way of defining a vector measure in the sense of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure) definition. But in that case, what vector measure are they defining? If they are not using that definition of vector measure, which definition are they using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen this exact notation before, but this is what I would assume it means.  Assume $\overline{\Omega}$ is compact.  Given an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued vector measure $\mathbf{y}$ on $\overline{\Omega}$, write $\mathbf{y}(A)=(y_1(A),y_2(A),\dots,y_d(A))$ for any Borel set $A$.  Then each $y_i$ is a signed measure on $\overline{\Omega}$.  Given a continuous function $f=(f_1,f_2,\dots,f_d):\overline{\Omega}\to\mathbb{R}^d$, we can then define $$\langle\mathbf{y},f\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^d\int_{\overline{\Omega}} f_i dy_i .$$

This gives a bounded linear map $\langle\mathbf{y},\cdot\rangle:C(\overline{\Omega},\mathbb{R}^d)\to\mathbb{R}$.  Conversely, a vector version of the Riesz-Markov theorem says that any bounded linear map $C(\overline{\Omega},\mathbb{R}^d)\to\mathbb{R}$ comes from a unique vector measure on $\overline{\Omega}$ in this way.  So if your vector measure $\mathbf{y}$ is presumably being defined as (the restriction to $\Omega$ of) the unique vector measure on $\overline{\Omega}$ that gives rise to the specified bounded linear map $C(\overline{\Omega},\mathbb{R}^d)\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Great. So you can recover the vector measure coordinate by coordinate evaluating the operator at an indicator function in the $i$-th place. Thanks!